# How to access a variable of two class in JSP loop

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, collections

I've got two classes:

```
 public Car
      Integer number;
      String  name;

  public Parking
      Integer parkingNumber;
      String address;
```

I sent to my JSP one List of Parking and  one List of Car

```
 List<Parking> parkingList= new ArrayList<Parking>();
 List<Car> carList= new ArrayList<Car>();
```

but full of values(they are not important for the example)

```
Model.addAttribute("parkingList", parkingList);
Model.addAttribute("carList", carList);`
```

How can i access inside a loop(foreach) to a car->name of a car with a car->number = a defined Parking->parkingNumber (assume for example this is 5) ?

```
   <c:forEach items="${parkingList}" var="park" varStatus="status"> 
       <p> $carList[park.parkingNumber=5].name</p>
  </c:forEach>
```

Is it correct?
Unluckly I can't use another Foreach because the car.name value must be wrote in the page only one time.

Comment: Have you tried using the `foreach` loops for both lists as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: The problem is that adding another foreach i'll have more than one <p>car.name</p> while i need it printed only one time

Comment: That can't do it either...for my project i need to check that inside the jsp unluckly

Answer (score 2):

Below line in your code seems to be incorrect

```
 <p> $car[park.parkingNumber=5].name</p>
```

Because you are setting below values in model

```
Model.addAttribute("parkingList", parkingList); 
Model.addAttribute("car", car);
```

where you are putiing single Car object in model and you are trying to access it like an  array `$car[park.parkingNumber=5].name`

You can directly say `car.name`

Comment: Thank you, you are completly right. I'm sorry but that won't help me. What i was really trying to understand is how to access in the case I sent to the JSP a carList like the parking List. Now i edit my question.

Comment: I am not clear about your question **How can i access inside a loop(foreach) to a car->name of a car with a car->number = a defined Parking->parkingNumber (assume for example this is 5) ?**. Can you explain it properly?

Comment: I want to access the car name variable for  printing it in the jsp, but only if the car number variable is equal to the parkingNumber variable of the class parking @Sachin Mesare. Unfortunatly i have to do this check insede the JSP and I dont know how..

Comment: you can add one more for loop  inside it and then add a check for car.number

Comment: I have to print the value in the JSP inside the <p> </p> only one time unluckly....if I add one more loop it become wrote more than one time @Sachin Mesare

Comment: You should put the print statement inside `if` condition, so that it will  print only if it matches the condition :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126207/discussion-between-sachin-mesare-and-user2298581).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<c:forEach items="${parkingList}" var="park" varStatus="parkStatus"> 
   <c:forEach items="${carList}" var="car" varStatus="carStatus"> 
      <c:if test="car.number eq park.parkingNumber">
         <p><c:out value="car.name" /></p>
      </c:if>
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

**OR**

If you do not wish to use multiple `foreach` loops, on server side, you can use `Car` class in `Parking` class like,

```
public Parking
  Integer parkingNumber;
  String address;
  List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And put the `Car`'s  list in the `Parking` object where all cars having same number as parkingNumber.

```
for(Parking parking : parkingList) {
  for(Car car : carList) {
    if (car.getNumber() == parking.getParkingNumber()) {
      parking.getCarList().add(car);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you have to just iterate this once and you will get all the cars which has same parking number.

```
<c:forEach items="${parkingList}" var="park" varStatus="parkStatus"> 
   <c:forEach items="${park.carList}" var="car" varStatus="carStatus"> 
      <p><c:out value="car.name" /></p>
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```